# Construction of Dedekind reals using higher inductive-inductive types

Tags: real-analysis, fields, homotopy-type-theory

In the textbook Homotopy Type Theory: Univalent Foundations of Mathematics, the authors give a predicative constructive construction of the initial Cauchy complete reals $\mathbb{R}_C$ in terms of a higher inductive-inductive type ${\sim}_C$ defined at the same time as $\mathbb{R}_C$. Is there a similar construction of the initial Dedekind complete reals $\mathbb{R}_D$ as a higher inductive-inductive type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dedekind reals are constructed as Dedekind cuts in section 11.2 of the HoTT book. A Dedekind cut is a pair $(L,U)$ of subsets of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying the conditions listed at the beginning of the section. The Dedekind reals as a type are therefore *not* a higher inductive-inductive type, but are rather a **dependent sum** of the form
$$\Sigma (L \,{:}\, P\mathbb{Q}) \,\Sigma (U \,{:}\, P\mathbb{Q}) \; \mathrm{isCut}(L,U).$$
Nevertheless, there is something to be said about predicativity and higher inductive-inductive types. A question arises what we should do about $P \mathbb{Q}$, which is supposed to be the powerset of rational numbers, but HoTT does not have powersets. If you keep reading the section, you will find a discussion of the possibilities, some of which are more impredicative than others.

One of the options listed is to avoid all impredicativity by setting $P \mathbb{Q} = (\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{S})$, where $\mathbb{S}$ is the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), constructed as a higher inductive-inductive type, namely the *initial $\omega$-frame*. This is the initial lattice with $0$, $1$, binary meets $\wedge$ and countable joins $\bigvee_{n : \mathbb{N}}$, satisfying the distributivity law $p \wedge \bigvee_n q_n = \bigvee_n (p \wedge q_n)$.
Note that we require here a higher inductive-inductive construction because one of the operations is infinitary (the finitary algebras are constructed as ordinary higher inductive types, see section 6.11 of the HoTT book).

The resulting notion of predicative Dedekind reals is maybe not what one really wants, but is still quite useful and has been studied, for example by [Davorin Lešnik](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/sl/imenik/137/lesnik-davorin/)'s dissertation (if anyone writes to him, ask him to put his PhD up on the web page as it disappeared recently), and by Paul Taylor and myself in [The Dedekind reals in Abstract Stone Duality](http://www.paultaylor.eu/ASD/dedras/).

Comment: We elaborate a little on the semantics of the initial $\omega$-frame [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.07339). Paper will be updated in the coming weeks.

Comment: @BasSpitters: When I wrote the answer I wondered if I could offer some reference about the initial $\omega$-frame. Thanks.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09254) by Thorsten Altenkirch claims that the Sierpinski space is just the partial function classifier $1_\bot$ of the unit type, and Altenkirch constructs the partiality monad as a quotient inductive-inductive type.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield: yes, it's the initial $\omega$-frame (or something very close to it). There are many ways to construct it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it answers your specific question, but as a general discussion of related things I recommend [The HoTT reals coincide with the Escardó-Simpson reals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05956) by Auke Booij.

Comment: That one is about Cauchy reals. The interesting observation is that by changing an $\exists$ in the definition of Dedekind reals to $\Sigma$ we get the Cauchy sequences of rationals, quotiented suitably. If we had countable choice, that would be the Cauchy completion of rationals.